# Managing blend modes on illustration

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, blending, layer-style

I have made pupil of eye by blending different layers in 2nd artboard but when i move it to my original sketch it become little transparent due to blending different layers. i cannot change blending to normal. So how can i solve this issue.

Comment: I have tried but it did not work. I might not clear about my question i wanted to ask that actually my path is blended. No matter i move that path on any layer, blended mode remains same as soft light described in appearance menu.

Comment: Select all the "blended objects" and group them. Select the entire group and in the transparency panel click the box "isolate blending"- this should keep the blending confined to the group so it does not affect other objects

Comment: Isolate blending in transparency panel worked. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @Kyle: please add your comment as an answer so it can be upvoted and accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Select all the "blended objects" and group them. Select the entire group and in the transparency panel click the box "isolate blending"- this should keep the blending confined to the group so it does not affect other objects.